# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function gzopen() when installing WordPress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm seeing the below error after attempting to activate a WordPress theme.  The error message in the browser is...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function gzopen() in /var/www/mysite.com/wp-content/themes/flat/themify/themify-builder/classes/class-themify-builder-layouts.php on line 528
```

Checking my `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I see the following error:

```
Call to undefined function gzopen() in /var/www/mywebsite.com/wp-      content/themes/flat/themify/themify-builder/classes/class-themify-builder-layouts.php on line     528, referer: http://mywebsite.com/wp-admin/update.php?action=upload-theme
```

Server information:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Apache: APache/2.4.7
PHP: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4
```

Answer (score 5):

That happened with me too (after upgrading to 14.04 #ubuntu). I waisted my whole day on it but in the end i found the solution.

replace `gzopen` with `gzopen64`.

this absolutely worked for me.
**PS:** I'll like the magento community to know that this problems appeared in creating package, after upgrading apache and php.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs because your PHP server is not compiled with Zlib (this PHP module allows you to read and write .gz compressed files). Zlib support in PHP is not enabled by default.
More information about how to setup Zlip can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.setup.php

Comment: Searching that link... leads me to here: http://php.net/manual/en/zlib.installation.php , which indicates I need to configure "PHP --with-zlib[=DIR]".  I don't really understand what is meant.  Some more searching seems to indicate that I need to install zlib modules (apt-get install zlib1g-dev), and then edit my /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini to turn on zlib-output compression (http://www.namhuy.net/2430/install-enable-zlib-linux-server.html). Which I did.  However, I don't see how to recompile PHP with the changes to the .ini file.  Am I on the right track, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes,  you are on the right track. The provided article http://www.namhuy.net/2430/install-enable-zlib-linux-server.html gives good guidelines for setting up zlib. If you've executed all steps, you should have zlib enabled and the error would disappear.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  On http://www.namhuy.net/2430/install-enable-zlib-linux-server.html, I go to this step... "
zlib.output_compression_level = 6".  Then I rebooted my VM (so I could grab a snapshot of it), and tried reinstalling the theme.  But am getting the same error.  I didn't see anywhere in the steps about  recompiling PHP... do I still need to do that?

Comment: I'm thinking it might be better if you install a different version of php - one that is precompiled with zlib.

Comment: WHat about this - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/1315888, and this http://askubuntu.com/questions/459352/php-zlib-gzopen-not-exists ?  It looks like gzopen() became gzopen64 ... and is still broken.  Is there any way to map gzopen() to gzopen64()?

Comment: I am not aware of such way, sorry. The best i can advise you to do is make the code independable of zlib. To do that, extract the .gz manually and remove the gzopen call from the theme code, so the extracted file is used directly.